# Контроль ввода данных и readln

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

[image: Пример работы контроля ввода]Доброй ночи. Работаю в PascalABC.Net. Долго возился с контролем ввода и в итоге сделал его, однако считывает он теперь лишь переменную s и соот-но решение не дает, однако, если поставить за ним " readln(n); ", дабы считывал эту переменную, то он делает это отдельно от контроля ввода, т.е. сначала есть контроль ввода и выдает сообщение об ошибке в случае ввода букв, но после нажатия на ENTER начинает считывать переменную "n", на которую уже не работает контроль ввода. Скрин прилагается.  В общем тут я снова встал в тупик. 
Вот часть кода:

```
uses crt;
const num=5;
      c=0.00000001; {Константа для обхода деления на 0}
var a: array [1..num,1..num] of real;
    b, e: array [1..num] of real;
    n, i, j, k: integer;
           delenie: real;
v:integer;
s:string;
x:real;

begin
 clrscr;

 writeln('Решение СЛАУ по методу Гаусса.');
 repeat
 writeln;
 writeln('Введите колич-во неизвестных величин и нажмите ENTER:');
 readln(s);{читаем строку}
 val(s,x,v);{пытаемся преобразовать ее в число, в переменную C - упадет позиция, с недопустимым символом}
 if v<>0 then writeln('Должно быть число');
 until v=0;
 readln(n);

 begin
 writeln;
 writeln('Вводите коэфф-ты матpицы A по стpокам нажимая ENTER:');
   for k:=1 to n do
    for j:=1 to n do
     begin
      write ('a[',k,',',j,']=');
      read(a[k,j]);
     end;
  writeln;
   writeln('Введите вектоp В свободных членов нажимая ENTER:');
    for k:=1 to n do
     begin
      write ('b[',k,']=');
      read (b[k]);
     end;
```

Comment: я, возможно, чего-то не знаю о PascalABC.Net, но что это за такое обозначение с наклонными палочками - `read(a\[k,j\]);`?

Comment: @Igor, удивительно, но в моем коде их нет, видимо при вставке что-то не то произошло, сейчас попробую заново вставить

Comment: @Igor, вот, теперь нормально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
  if v<>0 then 
    writeln('Должно быть число')
  else
    n := Round(x);
until v=0;
//readln(n);
```

Comment: спасибо большое! Помогло! а не подскажете как можно сделать так, чтобы после ввода данных в матрицу, программа спрашивала всё ли верно введено и в случае если нет, то предлагала выбрать в какой именно строке?

Comment: @SergeyM Задайте, пожалуйста, отдельный вопрос.